# Error al importar base de datos Visual Studio 2022 en proyecto base de datos SQL

Tags: sql, visual-studio, importación

estoy con un problema y escribo en el foro para pedir ayudar. Resulta que creo un un proyecto de base de datos SQL en Visual Studio 2022 y al momento de importar la BD me tira un error que no tengo manera de saber el porque ni como solucionarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias

Comment: En la documentación oficial de Azure, para importar datos de mySql, te indica una serie de pasos a seguir, [Conexión mySqlWorkbech Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/mysql/single-server/connect-workbench). Además deberías de ser mucho más detallado con el escenario que tienes, para poder obtener una buena respuesta.

Comment: @Javifer2 gracias por responder. Es cierto que el desarrollo de la consulta no está bien en detalle, pido disculpas por eso. El tema es que la base de datos no está en Azure ni nada de eso. Me quiero conectar a una instancia local de SQLEXPRESS y ahí es cuando lanza el error y no se porque me indica ese error con Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Al final pude solucionarlo desintanlando Visual Studio con todos sus componentes y hacer una instalación en limpio. Con eso se solucionó. Quedará para otro momento saber el porque lanzaba ese error.
Gracias a todos.